# No nontrivial group homomorphism $ \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to show that there is no nontrivial group homomorphism between
$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}
$$
with $n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq1$.

Now I know that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} = 0+n\mathbb{Z},1+n\mathbb{Z},...,(n-1)+n\mathbb{Z}$ and that this is a group with "+", the same goes for $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. But I have no idea how to prove that there is no other group homomorphism. if $f$ is a homomorphism, then $f(0+n\mathbb{Z})=0$ since $0$ and $0+n\mathbb{Z}$ are the neutral elements in both groups. But where do I go from here? It is clear that 
$$
f: \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}, f(a+n\mathbb{Z})=a
$$
is no group homomorphism because
$$
f(0+n\mathbb{Z})=f((1+n\mathbb{Z})+(n-1)+n\mathbb{Z})= 1+n-1=n\neq0
$$
so this is wrong. For the same reason it also cannot be $f(a+n\mathbb{Z})=x$ for $x\neq 0$. But from here on I find no more argumentation to show the rest and would appreciate your help very much.

EDIT// with the help from below:
Assume $f(1+n\mathbb{Z})=a\neq0.$
$$
0=f(0+n\mathbb{Z})=f(n+n\mathbb{Z})=f((1+...+1)+n\mathbb{Z})=f((1+n\mathbb{Z})+...+(1+n\mathbb{Z}))= f(1+n\mathbb{Z})+...+f(1+n\mathbb{Z})=n\cdot a\neq0
$$
so $f(1+n\mathbb{Z})=0$ but then because all $b\in \mathbb{Z}_+, b\neq 0$ can written as a sum of 1 we get the same result as above, which is zero.

Comment: You're on the right track.  So $f$ has to send the class of $1$ somewhere.  You may assume it sends $1$ to some $0 \neq a \in \mathbb Z$. Then what?

Comment: More hint – show $f$ has to send the class of $n+1$ to two different places (which is absurd).

Comment: In $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, $\underbrace{1+1+1+...+1}_{n\text{ times}}=0$, but we don't have $n1=n=0$ for any $n>0 \in\mathbb Z$

Comment: @D_S, Gerry & Tanner, thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can solve the problem now, King, let me encourage you to write it up and to post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, King.

Comment: hey @GerryMyerson, I edited my post with the solution, is that not ok?

Comment: Didn't occur to me to look for the answer in the question. Was expecting it to be posted as an answer. It's OK.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Homomorphisms have the property that $h(a)$ has order dividing the order of $a$ for each $a$, if the order of $a$ is finite.

Comment: $\begin{align} 0 &= n\ \alpha\ \ =\ \ \alpha\  \ +\ \  \cdots\, +\ \alpha\\
\smash{\overset{\large h(\ )}\Longrightarrow}\ \ 0 &= nh(\alpha)\! =\! h(\alpha) + \cdots\, + h(\alpha)\end{align}\ \ \ $

Comment: So if $h:X\to Y$ and $X$ has torsion, then so does $Y$. @BillDubuque

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $G$ is a finite group, then there is no nontrivial group homomorphism $\phi: G \to \mathbb Z$.

Indeed, the image of $\phi$ is a finite subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ and so must be the trivial subgroup.